# Vaadin 24 blocks requests to REST endpoints, despite having extra Security Configuration for them

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

despite having this extra Configuration for my REST-Endpoints:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestSecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")))
                    // .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/**")).permitAll()
                    );
            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
        public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
            return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
        }
    }
```

with @Order(1) and the Security Configuration extending VaadinWebSecurity for the Frontend, I get this response on postman requests.

[image]

I have tried all the things I found in the Vaadin Forum and here on Stack Overflow, but I'm not getting around this response. Also adding the requestmatchers for /api/** in the SecurityConfig for Vaadin, doesn't help.

Some additional information:
I'm using Webflux for my backend and Spring Boot v3.2.0.

Does anyone of you have an another idea, I'm blocked with my project by this issue since two days.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with the security, but with Vaadin itself.

Take a close look at the result:

- Status 200
- Vaadin Bootstrap HTML

If you don't want to battle this, you either move Vaadin away from the
root:

> ```
> vaadin.urlMapping=/my_mapping/*
> ```
>
> ---
>
> https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/spring/configuration#using-spring-boot-properties

Or you can (since 23.3) exclude URLs from the Vaadin servlet to handle:

> The list of URL patterns that should not be handled by the Vaadin servlet, can be configured using the vaadin.exclude-urls property in the form of a comma-separated string.
>
> ```
> # application.properties
> vaadin.exclude-urls=/swagger-ui/**,/custom-service/**
> ```
>
> ---
>
> https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/integrations/spring/configuration#prevent-handling-of-specific-urls

Comment: While this is correct; I would like to highlight that it's not Vaadin's fault but a misconfiguration. OP could also fix this by adding Order to the Bean and not Configuration and re-adding the securityMatcher to their API security chain.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
I had the Annotation @EnableWebFlux in this module, because I used it without Vaadin before, which was one part of the problem. The other part was to add 
http.securityMatcher("/api/**").csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable); in my SecurityConfig-File.
Then it worked.